# ¿como incluir 6 condiciones en una consulta sql uniendo dos tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

tengo dos tabla la primera es muro(usuario,urls,puntos) la segunda es historial(urls,uqvlp,uqrlv,fecha) en el cual la columna uqvlp hace referencia a usuario que vio la pagina, y uqrlv que es usuario que recibio la visita.
quiero hacer en una solo consulta sql que me seleccione ambas tablas luego que me no imprima la fila del usuario actual, que si muro es distinto a cero, que si el  uqvlp es distinto al usuario actual, que si ese enlace no ha cumplido un dia desde que lo visito que no lo muestre, y por ultimo que el uqrlv sea distinto al usuario que publico su enlace.
no se si me di a entender

quiero que cuando haga click en el enlace no lo vuelva a ver durante 24 horas cumpliendo con las demás condiciones

esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, pero aun asi no hace lo que quiero

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

SELECT muro.urls, muro.usuario, muro.puntos, historial.uqvlp, 
       historial.uqrlv 
FROM muro 
left join historial on muro.urls=historial.urls 
where(historial.uqvlp is null or historial.uqvlp<>'$user') 
and muro.puntos<>0 and historial.fecha > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND historial.fecha <= NOW()
```

no me devuelve ningun error solo que cuando lo ejecuto, me sigue apareciendo un usuario que vio el enlace y no deberia de aparecer solo hasta que transcurra las 24 horas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Fijate en tus condiciones.. historial.fecha es mayor a ahora-24? siempre.. y historia.fecha es menor que ahora.. siempre... entonces siempre va a entrar por ahi...

Comment: La condicion es solo historial.fecha + 24hs < now.. y ahi si funciona...

Comment: no entendí bien a que te refieres

Comment: Lee los enlaces que te pase.. y luego, proba tus condiciones.. vas a ver que estan mal...